# Javascript can't make button change the color of a box

Tags: javascript, html, colors

```
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function({
  document.getElementById("box").body.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
});
```

is not changing the color of the box when i click it, where is the fault in the code?

Comment: And your ("*[mcve]*") HTML? Any errors in the console?

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("box").body.style.backgroundColor` with `document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor`

Comment: im very new to this, i have a grow function that is working which is //Grow Button
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";});
//Blue Button
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("box").body.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to delete `.body` since you already selected the element with the id of box before it.

```
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener(
    "click", 
    function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` to select your elements.And handle click event for button like this.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#button2");//select your button
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){//handle click event
document.querySelector("#box").style.backgroundColor="Blue";//select box id and set background
});
```

```html
<button id="button2"/>Click</button>
<p id="box">
change color
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.There are two ways to do that

First::

```js
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener(
        "click", 
        function(){
            document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
        }
    );
```

Second::If you have body tag in your DOM

```js
document.body.getElementById("button2").addEventListener(
        "click", 
        function(){
            document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
        }
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your javascript should look like this:

`document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Blue"; });`

Comment: Please provide an explanation is to _why_ this works, rather than just posting code.